# Detecting where a webrequest came from in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want create a plugin that detects whether a user navigated to another page by clicking on a link or by typing in a new URL in the omnibar.

Is it possible in a Chrome extension to detect whether a webrequest was made from within a page or by a user from the omnibox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone trying to find out how to do this:

You can use the following function: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation.html#event-onCommitted

It gives back whether a request came from the address bar.